# Access column using dictreader

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

**The problem**:

I have been having an issue trying to find the average of a column from a csv file using python's dictreader.

**I have tried**:

Accessing the columns like this using the column name, this works but the column name is required and im unsure how to loop over the reader.fieldnames in a way to construct a list from just each single column rather than mixing all columns data into the same list :

```
          for r in reader:
            print(r.get("Price"))
```

**Example of the loop**

```
for i in reader.fieldnames:
    for r in reader:
        print(row.get(i))
```

This is fine, however prints out 1 element from each column for each row. This makes it difficult to assemble a list of say all prices, all names etc as it would just rebuild the dictreader in list form.

**Question**

How can i read just a single entire column from dictreader so i can access each column individually as a list and perform operations on it?

**Note**: so far i have tried appending each element using the loop, but results in a N size array with 4 elements in each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're fine looping over your file once for each column you want to read, just build a dict comprehension of list comprehensions:

```
columns = {fieldname: [row.get(fieldname) for row in reader] for fieldname in reader.fieldnames}
```

There's not really a better way to do it, just based on the nature of the file... csv's are a series of rows, turning them into columns is gonna be a little wasteful. You can tinker with this if you only want certain fieldnames extracted.

If you really need to only read the file once, though:

```
columns = {}
for row in reader:
    for fieldname in reader.fieldnames:
        columns.setdefault(fieldname, []).append(row.get(fieldname))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) module. It is very powerful and can deal with csv files.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
saved_column = df['column_name']
```

Comment: Good advice and thanks for answering! but im ideally not wanting to use any extra libraries beyond csv etc.

Comment: `pandas` and `petl` are both excellent choices if your dataset is of any substantial size, or if the requirements of your project begin to grow. My answer was definitely the naive "Programming 101" solution, in the wild you would expect to use one of those modules.

Comment: @ToreEschliman - If you don't need the full functionality of a Pandas DataFrame - if you can accomplish the task easily using *built-ins*, it might not be worthwhile to add extraneous modules to the namespace.

Answer (score 1):

```
data.csv:
'''
one, two, three
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
10,11,12
'''
```

Use a *plain* reader object, get the headers, transpose the data, combine the headers with the data to create a dict.

```
import csv
with open('data.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    headers = next(reader)
    # transpose the data
    # --> columns become rows and rows become columns
    data = zip(*reader)
    # create a dictionary by combining the headers with the data
    d = dict(zip(headers, data))
```

---

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(d)
{' three': ('3', '6', '9', '12'),
 ' two': ('2', '5', '8', '11'),
 'one': ('1', '4', '7', '10')}
>>>
```